# Созданные мною процессы завершаются на Win Server 2012 R2. Java

Tags: java

У меня есть приложение, которое при старте создаёт вспомогательные процессы, которые общаются с помощью RMI.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

При попытке запустить это приложение на Win Server 2012 R2 оно создаёт процессы и тут же их убивает, не давая даже им полностью запуститься.

Команда  для запуска верная.
Если запускать процесс той же командой, что и основное приложение - оно запустится.
На Win 10 приложение работает, пробовал на разных версиях: Pro, Enterprise.

Что может убивать процессы при их запуске ?

### UPD

На Ubuntu тоже всё прекрасно работает.
Прошу обратить внимание, процессы запускаются, но убиваются сразу же. Причем если я закрою основное приложение, другие процессы должны закрыться, но тут другая ситуация, они мало того что не закрываються, а могут продолжить работу прям как должны делать это изначально.

Comment: Что-то не понятно, может прав нет? Или ошибки какие есть?

Comment: Та я и сам не понимаю почему так происходит, ошибок вообще никаких нет.
Может настройки java в этой версии винды какие-то уникальные ?

Comment: пробовали stdout процесса читать?

Comment: а версии JVM совпадают?

Comment: Да, совпадают. Если бы не совпадали - приложение бы не открылось. А так убиваются только подпроцессы после создания.